# How to generate a string by concatenating another string with an environment variable

Tags: variables, string-manipulation, environment-variables

I need to create a variable with a fool folder direct which need to concatenate from a environment variable and the end notes

```
function! MyFoo(arg)
    let repo=$Project + "/cfora"                #Q1      
    let build=$project + "/build/cfora/debug"   
    exec "!cd build"                            
    exec "!cmake repo"                          #02
endfunction
```

Question:

Q1: How can I concatenate the value of the environment variable `$Project` with the end node string `/cfora` into one string and assign it to a new variable `repo`?

Q2: How can I refer the variable in the string not print the variable name? For example here, I want to ultimately run `cmake /root/to/the/project/repo`, not `cmake repo`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In vim dot is a concatenation operator:

```
let repo = $Project . '/cfora'
```

To "refer" variable in the string, well, in your case it is just a concatenation again:

```
exe '!cmake ' . repo
```

**PS**

I would suggest to use built in make facilities for this.

And vim `lcd` instead of `exe '!cd ...`

Comment: If you have read this answer only, read also the answer from Zoe if you are using recent vim versions.

Answer (score 6):

The answer has partly changed as of Vim 8.1 patch 1114, where `.` is becoming obsolete. While it's not currently wrong to use `.` in non-Vim9 vimscript (because backwards compatibility), you can use the `..` operator instead.

This does have a couple subjective and objective advantages. Quoting `:h expr-..`:

> For String concatenation ".." is preferred, since "." is ambiguous, it is also
> used for |Dict| member access and floating point numbers.
> In |Vim9| script and when |vimscript-version| is 2 or higher, using "." is not
> allowed.

In either case, `..` is the more modern option. As an aside, it's also the operator you'll want to use if you upgrade to Vim9script, though that requires a few other changes, and I'm not covering that here. See `:h Vim9` if this sounds interesting, and you have a relatively up-to-date Vim 8.2 install, or if you've installed Vim 9.0+.

With your current code, though, and Vim 8.1 with patch 1114, or newer, you can use:

```
let repo = $Project .. '/cfora'
```

This does the exact same thing as `$Project . '/cfora'`; whether you want to use `..` over `.` is up to you. The arguments in favor of it were mentioned earlier in this answer.

As for executing, you don't actually need to use `.` or `..` at all; by passing multiple strings, Vim concatenates them for you with a space:

```
exe '!cmake' repo
```

Vim interprets this as `exe '!cmake <content of the repo variable without brackets>'`. From `:h :execute`:

> ```
>       Multiple arguments are concatenated, with a space in
>       between.  To avoid the extra space use the ".."
>       operator to concatenate strings into one argument.
> ```

This also holds for some other similar-style keywords, including `echo` (and the related `echom` and `echoerr`), and likely a couple others that I don't remember off the top of my head.

---

While I'm writing an answer, this line does nothing:

```
exec "!cd build"
```

You're using `cd` in a subprocess, and because of how `cd` works, the subprocess cannot change the working directory of the parent process; in your case, that's Vim. This particular subprocess also dies immediately after changing the directory, and doesn't affect any other subprocesses made afterwards.

Assuming you're using Linux, or otherwise use Vim in such a way that it can use a UNIX shell, a valid command would be:

```
exec "!cd" build "&& cmake" repo
```

Alternatively, you can use `exec 'cd' build` on its own line; the main difference here is that `cd` in this context changes Vim's working directory, rather than a child process that immediately dies. As Maxim also mentioned, you can use `lcd` instead of `cd`, but it really depends on your use. `exec` without `!` executes the content as a Vim command, and `:cd` is indeed a valid Vim command.

Or even better, have CMake do it for you. I haven't tried this myself, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24435795/6296561) outlines it; see the second or third bullet point, depending on what version of CMake you're running. Using those flags should let you fully drop any form of `cd` from the command, and maintain compatibility with shells that don't support `&&` (particularly stock Windows). Concatenation is still needed to supply the parameters, so you should be able to do something like this (CMake 3.13+, assuming the flags work the way I think they do):

```
exec "!cmake -B" build "-S" repo
```

Comment: A note that when the string interpolation gets complex, `printf` might be a good alternative. Great answer :)